# Read infix expression into a stack

Tags: c++, stack, expression-trees, infix-notation

I've written code to convert an expression tree to preorder and postorder, but I'm struggling to actually build the expression tree from an infix expression. I have a .cc file that will call the build_expression_tree function, call the conversion functions and print out the converted expressions.

This is my current non-working function:

```
void Expression_Tree::build_expression_tree(char input[], int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) 
    {
        if (input[i] == ' ')
        {
            i++;
        }
        if(input[i] >= '0' && input[i] <= 9) 
        { 
            ETNode *temp = new ETNode;
            temp->left = temp->right = NULL;
            temp->input = input[i];

            tree_stack.push(temp);
        }
        else if (input[i] == '(') 
        {
            ETNode *temp = new ETNode;
            temp->left = temp->right = NULL;
            temp->input = input[i];

            tree_stack.push(temp);
        }
        else if (input[i] == ')')
        {
            while (tree_stack.top() != '(')
            {
                temp->right = tree_stack.top();
                tree_stack.pop();
                temp->left = tree_stack.top();
                tree_stack.pop();
                tree_stack.pop();
                tree_stack.push(temp);
            }
        }
        else if (input[i] == '+' || input[i] == '-' || input[i] == '*' || input[i] == '/')
        {
            while (!tree_stack.empty())
            {
                ETNode *temp = new ETNode;
                temp->left = temp->right = NULL;
                temp->input = input[i];

                tree_stack.push(temp);

                temp->right = tree_stack.top();
                tree_stack.pop();
                temp->left = tree_stack.top();
                tree_stack.pop();

                tree_stack.push(temp);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The errors I'm getting at this point are:
Expression_Tree.h:61:40: error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer

```
while(tree_stack.top() != '(')
```

Expression_Tree.h:62:13: error: 'temp' was not declared in this scope

```
temp->right = tree_stack.top();
```

Expression_Tree.h:62:13: error: 'temp' was not declared in this scope

```
temp->left = tree_stack.top();
```

I know why the last two errors (not declared in scope) are occurring, but I just don't know what to do to fix it whilst making my code work properly.

I don't even know if my code is completely wrong, but any tips would be incredibly appreciated! 
Thanks.

EDIT:
These are the classes that affect the Build_Expression_Tree function.

```
class ETNode {
public:
    char input;
    ETNode *left, *right;
};

class Expression_Tree { 
public:
    Expression_Tree() { root = 0; };
    ~Expression_Tree() { clear(root); }
    void build_expression_tree(char[], int);
    void inorder() { inorder(root); }
    void preorder() { preorder(root); }
    void postorder() {postorder(root); }
private:
    ETNode* root;
    std::stack<ETNode*> tree_stack;
    void visit(ETNode* p) { std::cout << p->input << " "; } 
    void inorder(ETNode*);
    void preorder(ETNode*);
    void postorder(ETNode*);
    void clear(ETNode*);
};
```

Comment: please show us what `tree_stack` and `ETNode` are

Comment: @vu1p3n0x I've edited the post

Comment: could you clarify, are you only using the stack as a building aid? and only using `root` for all other operations? or do you need the stack to be preserved in some manner?

Comment: also are `()`s mandatory in your input? or could someone write `(5 + 2 + 3)`?

Comment: @vu1p3n0x The stack is purely for building the tree, the build function is called by the tester function to send to the preorder/postorder functions before printing. 
These are the steps that I'm attempting to implement: 1. Read input into new tree nodes, add them to the stack until a right parenthesis is found.  2. Backtrack by popping three items off the stack. 3. Construct a subtree from these three items. 4. Remove the matching left parenthesis from the stack. 5. Add the subtree to the stack (really just the root node of the subtree). 6. Repeat 1–5 until all parentheses have been removed.

Comment: @vu1p3n0x the example I'm trying to use is: char input[] = {'2', '+', '(', '3', '*', '(', '2', '+', '2', ')', ')', '+', '5'}; So for example with that input, the postfix should be returned as: 2322+*+5+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I've split up your example input into a representation of how the stack can be used and the decisions made at each input.

```
//    _ = nullptr or empty
//    # = pointer to subtree (not just a number)
// | ___ |     |     |     begin (empty element on stack)
// | 2__ |     |     |  2  make number node and set to top->left if empty, else top->right
// | 2+_ |     |     |  +  set top->input if not set, else pop parent into left of new node
// | 2+_ | ___ |     |  (  make new node on stack
// | 2+_ | 3__ |     |  3  make number node and set to top->left if empty, else top->right
// | 2+_ | 3*_ |     |  *  set top->input if not set, else pop parent into left of new node
// | 2+_ | 3*_ | ___ |  (  make new node on stack
// | 2+_ | 3*_ | 2__ |  2  make number node and set to top->left if empty, else top->right
// | 2+_ | 3*_ | 2+_ |  +  set top->input if not set, else pop parent into left of new node
// | 2+_ | 3*_ | 2+2 |  2  make number node and set to top->left if empty, else top->right
// | 2+_ | 3*# |     |  )  pop it off into its parent
// | 2+# |     |     |  )  pop it off into its parent
// | #+_ |     |     |  +  set top->input if not set, else pop parent into left of new node
// | #+5 |     |     |  5  make number node and set to top->left if empty, else top->right
```

Note that I have many duplicate statements, one type for `(` one for `)` one for a number `0-9` and one for each operation `+-*/`. You already have these divisions in your code so you're on the right track.

`(`'s only job should be to create a new node on the top of the stack. In your code, there is no point to set `input = '('` because its going to be overwritten by an actual input later and its position in the stack is all that's needed to keep track of it. You should initialize `input` to `'\0'` or something else meaning empty.

`)`'s job should be to pop the top off the stack and put it where it needs to go. That'll be either the next top's left node if its null, otherwise it'll be top's right node. You don't need to loop down the stack like you do, because it'll always just be the top that we're interested in popping.

A number's job should be to create itself as a new node and put itself where it needs to go. Just like `)` that'll either be the top's left node if its null, otherwise it'll be top's right node. In your code, you make the node but you don't put it anywhere besides on the stack. Its not doing any good there because a number node will always be a leaf node (no right or left).

Finally an operation's job should be to simply set itself to the top's `input`. However, there's a special case where the top has already been filled in (when you do `1+2+3` the `1+2` is the node on top). So what you can do in that case is pop off the top, push a new node on top, add the old top as the left, and THEN just set itself to top's `input`. You don't need a loop.

After all is done, you can just set `root = tree_stack.top()`.

If you want the code I can supply it but I hope my explanation is enough.

**Code:** This seems to work for me

```
void Expression_Tree::build_expression_tree(char input[], int size)
{
  // assuming empty tree_stack, it shouldn't really be a member 
  // variable since its only used for building
  //std::stack<ETNode*> tree_stack;

  // make empty node, should really make a default constructor set all this up
  tree_stack.push(new ETNode);
  tree_stack.top()->left  = nullptr;
  tree_stack.top()->right = nullptr;
  tree_stack.top()->input = '\0';

  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
  {
    if (input[i] == ' ')
    {
      i++;
    }
    if (input[i] >= '0' && input[i] <= '9') // this 9 had a typo before
    {
      // create number leaf
      ETNode *temp = new ETNode;
      temp->left = nullptr;
      temp->right = nullptr; 
      temp->input = input[i];

      // put where it needs to go
      if (tree_stack.top()->left == nullptr)
        tree_stack.top()->left = temp;
      else
        tree_stack.top()->right = temp;
    }
    else if (input[i] == '(')
    {
      // make empty node
      ETNode *temp = new ETNode;
      temp->left = nullptr;
      temp->right = nullptr;
      temp->input = '\0';

      tree_stack.push(temp);
    }
    else if (input[i] == ')')
    {
      // pop top from the stack
      ETNode *temp = tree_stack.top();
      tree_stack.pop();

      // put where it needs to go
      if (tree_stack.top()->left == nullptr)
        tree_stack.top()->left = temp;
      else
        tree_stack.top()->right = temp;
    }
    else if (input[i] == '+' || input[i] == '-' || input[i] == '*' || input[i] == '/')
    {
      // shuffle node if already filled
      if (tree_stack.top()->input != '\0')
      {
        ETNode *old = tree_stack.top();
        tree_stack.pop();

        ETNode *temp = new ETNode;
        temp->left = old;
        temp->right = nullptr;

        tree_stack.push(temp);
      }

      tree_stack.top()->input = input[i];
    }
  }

  // set root node
  root = tree_stack.top();
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I've attempted to convert my code to follow your steps and I think I've gotten it fairly close but I'm still struggling with getting it to work overall. If you wouldn't mind, I would love your code to be able to cross-reference and understand where I'm going wrong. If not, no worries I'll try to keep grinding it out. Thanks heaps

Comment: Edited to give some code. Hope it helps you understand it a bit better.

Answer (score 0):

A quick look reveals that you need a `ETNode *temp = new ETNode;` just after `while(tree_stack.top() != '(')`. I did not check the logic, though.

Comment: Yeah thanks, it's more the while loop error that's an issue.